# Проблема с клавишами f1-f12 на клавиатуре HP

Tags: клавиатура, hp

Пролил кривыми руками кофе на клаву ноута Samsung, половина кнопок перестала работать. Я сходил в магазин, купил новую клавиатуру, присоединил к ноутбуку, и появилась следующая проблема.

Функциональные клавиши f1-f12 работают без зажатой fn и fn lock. А я очень часто использую их при разработке, и жать постоянно fn для каждого действия малоприятно. Пробовал разные комбинации клавиш, которые нашёл в гугле, но ничего не изменилось. Пишут, что на ноутбуках hp это якобы переключается в биосе, но у меня нет такой опции в биосе, да и вряд-ли должно быть. Клавиатура же не родная. Может кто уже имел подобные проблемы, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Пробовали fn + левый shift? (удерживайте fn и кратковременно нажмите shift)

Comment: https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c02035108

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его можно быстрее решить в сервисном центре HP (клавиатура) или Samsung (ноутбук)

Comment: @L.F.C. если его можно быстро закрыть, то зачем мне искать и ехать в сервисный центр, когда это можно с делать дома?

Comment: @Kvilios, да, не работает